# jQuery doesn't work with new elements (event delegation)

Tags: html, jquery

I've got a simple HTML page that displays a table with a value and a button for each row.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="row_1" data-row="1">
        <td><input type="text" id="comment_1" value="Value 1"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="button_display">Display</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_2" data-row="2">
        <td><input type="text" id="comment_2" value="Value 2"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="button_display">Display</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_0">
        <td colspan=2>
            <select id="dropdown_list">
                <option value="0">Select a new row</option>
                <option value="3">Elem 3</option>
                <option value="4">Elem 4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I've got a jQuery script with 2 functions :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('change', '#dropdown_list', function() {         // Add a row
        if ( $("#dropdown_list").val() != "0") {
            var selected_item = $("#dropdown_list").val();
            $("#row_0").before('<tr id="row_"'+selected_item+'" data-row="'+selected_item+'"><td><input type="text" id="comment_'+selected_item+'" value="Value '+selected_item+'"></td><td><button type="submit" class="button_display">Display</button></td></tr>');
            $("#dropdown_list option[value='"+selected_item+"']").remove(); // remove from dropdown list
            $('#dropdown_list').val(0); // dropdown list value set to 00
        }
    });
        
    $(".button_display").on( "click", function() {              // Display the value of a row
        var selected_line = $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-row');
        var new_comment = $("#comment_"+selected_line).val();
        console.log('Value : ' + new_comment);
    });
});
```

When you choose an element of the dropdown list, a row is added in the table.

When you press the button of the first or second row, the text value is shown in the console.
But if you press the button of a new added row, nothing happens.

I know that's a problem of event delegation and I've seen a lot of posts about this problem.
But I thought that using `$(document).on('change'` was enough to solve my problem.

So I don't see what is wrong in my code, despite hours of research.

Regards,
Olivier.

Comment: Also change `$(".button_display").on( "click", function() {` to `$(document).on( "click", ".button_display", function() {` as it is being added on runtime.

Comment: since the buttons are getting added dynamically as well so change `$(".button_display").on( "click", function() {` to `$('tbody').on( "click", ".button_display", function() {`

Comment: You need event delegation on dynamically added elements - ie the `.button_display` - the #dropdown_list doesn't need delegation as it exists when the page loads and is not added dynamically.  (technically: it exists before your code runs so does not need event delegation)